# R function for ROC or sensitivity anlysis for survey data

Tags: r, survey, roc

im working on NHIS 2020 survey and cant find a function for ROC or sensitivity anlysis for logistic regression model
is there any function known??
one more Q is there any function for splitting the survey data into training and test ?

im trying to split the survey data not a data frame

```
data <- svydesign(id=~PPSU, strata=~PSTRAT, 
                     nest = TRUE, 
                     weights=~WTFA_A,
                     data=dat)
```

and i had made glm model after i had split the data into 0.2\0.8 and after that i transformed it into survey design (not sure if this is right thing to do)

```
glm10 <- svyglm(PAIFRQ3M_A ~ NOTCOV_A+ SOCERRNDS_A +WELLNESS_A+
                 COGMEMDFF_A+CURJOBSD_A+SMKEV_A +DRK12MN_A+ 
                 CURJOBSD_A+CVDDIAG_A+ANXLEVEL_A*SMKEV_A+
                 AFVET_A*FGEFRQTRD_A+OPDCHRONIC_A+COMDIFF_A+PHSTAT_A*HOSPONGT_A+
                 EMPDYSMSS2_A+PHSTAT_A+SLPHOURS_A,
               design=as.svrepdesign(train.data) ,na.action=na.omit ,family=quasibinomial)
```

the sensitivity test i ran was :

```
fitted<-predict(glm10, return.replicates=TRUE, type="response") 

sensitivity<-function(pred,actual) mean(pred>0.1 & actual)/mean(actual) withReplicates(fitted, sensitivity, actual=glm10$PAIFRQ3M_A)
```

but i get an error Error: unexpected symbol in "sensitivity<-function(pred,actual) mean(pred>0.1 & actual)/mean(actual) withReplicates"

Answer (score 2):

I have created some sample data and code below that may point you in the correct direction, but your question is quite broad so might not answer everything. The `caTools` package can help with splitting into test/train. The `pROC` package can help with ROC.

```r
set.seed(05062020)
# Create sample data
alldata <- data.frame(outcome = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                      predictor1 = sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE),
                      predictor2 = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE))

# Split into testing and training
library(caTools)
sample <- sample.split(alldata$outcome, SplitRatio = 0.7)
train <- subset(alldata, sample == TRUE)
test <- subset(alldata, sample == FALSE)

# Run example logistic model
example_model <- glm(outcome ~., family = binomial, data = train)

# get prediction from fitted model
predicts <- predict(example_model, type = "response", newdata = test[,-which(names(test) == "outcome")])

# ROC and plot
library(pROC)
roc(test$outcome, predicts) #ROC

plot.roc(smooth(roc(test$outcome, predicts)), col = 1, lwd = 3, 
         main = "AUC", xlab = "1 - Specificity", legacy.axes = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `pROC` package.

To split the data, you need to decide how to split it. For example, you may use half as training data, half as test data. Assume `dataset` is your dataset. It has 10,000 rows

```
default_idx = sample(nrow(dataset), 5000)
default_trn = dataset[default_idx, ]
default_tst = dataset[-default_idx, ]
```

You can then get the ROC like this:

```
model_glm = glm(DV ~ IV, data = default_trn, family = "binomial")

test_prob = predict(model_glm, newdata = default_tst, type = "response")
test_roc = roc(default_tst$DV ~ test_prob, plot = TRUE, print.auc = TRUE)
```

See for example here for more detailed explanations: https://daviddalpiaz.github.io/r4sl/logistic-regression.html#roc-curves